# How can i store request.responseData into NSdictionary for parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

When i request to my web server it send me Json string in request.response.i want to store that json into NSDictionary for parsing and storing it into database.
My Json format is

```
{ "rowNumber" : 3,
   [ { "Age" : "2 - 4 years old ",
   "AndroidID" : "2",
   "Category" : "Chanson",
   "Description" : "fourni",
   "Size" : 3447196,
   "Thumbnail" : null,
   "Title" : "test",
   "iTunesID" : "2",
   "inactive" : false,
   "product_id" : 2} ],

   [ { "Age" : "2 - 4 years old ",
   "AndroidID" : "3",
   "Category" : "Chanson",
   "Description" : "Animation ",
   "Size" : 3447196,
   "Thumbnail" : null,
   "Title" : "Escargot",
   "iTunesID" : "3",
   "inactive" : false,
   "product_id" : 3
    } ] 
     }
```

IF i use this code to print String by string to NSlog it display fine but How i can i store that into NDdictionary ??

```
NSString *response = [[request responseString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

To store into dictionary i tried this code but this store my json in reverse order

```
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

for(NSString *key in [json allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:key]);
```

it store it into reverse order. Any help is appreciated.I am using ASIFormDataRequest for networking.

Comment: `NSDictionary` is not an ordered collection. If you wish to order it, sort the keys using a `NSArray`.

Comment: Your json is not in valid format.

Comment: @alex-i Can you please explain me in details?..do you have example..

Comment: Ideally an array should be comprised of objects of same type. Your json is not in a valid format, it's very unclear for what purpose the "rowNumber" is there. Your product is inside an array for no apparent reason. Given these details we can give some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid.

I check at

1. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
2. http://jsonviewer.net/

Your array format is wrong. Read JSON syntax [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

This is how it should be done:

```
{ "rowNumber" : 3,
   "Data" : [ { 
    "Age" : "2 - 4 years old ",
   "AndroidID" : "2",
   "Category" : "Chanson",
   "Description" : "fourni",
   "Size" : 3447196,
   "Thumbnail" : null,
   "Title" : "test",
   "iTunesID" : "2",
   "inactive" : false,
   "product_id" : 2 
   } ,
   { 
   "Age" : "2 - 4 years old ",
   "AndroidID" : "3",
   "Category" : "Chanson",
   "Description" : "Animation ",
   "Size" : 3447196,
   "Thumbnail" : null,
   "Title" : "Escargot",
   "iTunesID" : "3",
   "inactive" : false,
   "product_id" : 3
    } ] 
}
```

Then to store JSON data, I recommend you using my technique [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958883/ios-serialize-deserialize-complex-json-generically-from-nsobject-class/16771574#16771574). Proper way and quite a beast

Comment: @Malcolm yes the json format which you give me is valid one.. when i request to my server server response me this json with N number of Data item..rownumber is used for how many item i want to display in row and DATA is array of item that i want to display in tableview...

Comment: When i request to my server to give me list for tableview at that request it send me direct json (no url of json)

Answer (score 0):

- Json is parsed and output is NSArray or NSDicitonary
- You added wrong json.Not proper format
- NSdictionary doesn't have an order as you say.It is a key-value pair mechanism.That is it stores as a value for a key using `setObject:ForKey:` method and gives the value back when asked with same key used to set the value using `objectForKey:` method